# как в css сделать последовательность что бы следующие идущие классы были другого цвета и чередовались?

Tags: css

нужно что бы идущие по порядку классы первый first а следующие за ним second были чередующим цветом, а дальше когда обратно встречается first заново чередовался как на картинке
классы идут по порядку

нужно

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а сейчас

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.first{
  color: red;
}

.first ~ .second:nth-child(even) {
  color: blue;

}

.first ~ .second:nth-child(odd){
color:green;
}
```

```html
<div class="first">aa first</div>
  <div class="second">bb second</div>
  <div class="second">bb second</div>
  <div class="second">bb second</div>
  <div class="first">aa first</div>
  <div class="first">aa first</div>
  <div class="second">bb second</div>
  <div class="second">bb second</div>
```

Comment: Очень хочется сказать "никак" (не обернув их в дополнительные блоки). А вопрос ради интереса или решение на JS тоже прокатит?

Comment: у меня react и таблица это просто пример) js туда сложновато будет добавить( а на js это можно будет сделать?

Comment: реакт это и есть js

Comment: я знаю про реакт что js)

Comment: ну если не сложно скиньте пример на js

Comment: @recile, если ты знаешь что реакт это и так js почему говоришь что его сложно добавить? раз он уже есть

Comment: ну не сложно просто по другому, просто я пользуюсь react table v7 а она использует hooks и она еще в бете и в нете примеров особо нету, вот я и говорю что сложнее

Comment: чтобы получить решение для реакт, нужно как минимум добавить в вопрос [mcve] на реакте воспроизводящий твою проблему

Comment: это бесполезно даже на английском не отвечают про react-table v7, из-за этого и выложил css(только на issue в гите)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98158/discussion-between-grundy-and-recile).

Comment: как возможный вариант я выложил, если данных знаешь не много будет

Answer (score 1):

если данных не много будет, то как вариант сойдет

```
.first{
  color: red;
}
.first + .second{
    color:blue;
}
.first + .second + .second{
    color:green;
}
.first + .second + .second + .second{
    color:blue;
}
.first + .second + .second + .second + .second{
    color:green;
} 
.first + .second + .second + .second + .second + .second{
    color:blue;
}
```